# How can I fix a potty training seat being cold?

Tags: potty-training

My son is five and has a potty training seat similar to one as listed on Wish: Potty Training Toilet Seat for Kids. He just complained about it being cold for his bottom. He is much worse with the regular seat-making a mess of it and not cleaning his bottom. There don't seem to be many covers for seats like that.  I want him to as comfortable as possible going to do excreta- how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hair dryer to warm the seat up a bit before your son sits down.
(Store the hair dryer up and out of the way to avoid injuries.)